# How to run vbscript on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: scripts

I ve just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I want to use vbscript for cding on my website, because we have the vbscript for our study course [ class 11 multimedia cbse]. but I cannot find a browser to run it. I really dont have any idea about any alternative. Also i dont know about any emulator like we have for android on windows. Please help, I have to practise and we have practicals in a week. Also my laptop is quite old so windows does not work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run a vb script through Ubuntu. There are however some alternatives

- **Try installing `Internet Explorer` in `wine`**

Download [Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43) and save it to your home directory

Open a terminal and type:

```
wine IE8-WindowsXP-x86-ENU.exe
```

try running your script through IE

- **Install a Windows (through virtualbox for example)**

1) [Install](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-VirtualBox) Oracle VM VirtualBox.

2) Extract an ISO image from a Windows XP CD you have, `IMGburn` and `k3b` have this functionality.

3) Click the `New` button (the first of the four below the menu).

4) Use the Wizard to create a virtual partition for Windows XP. Windows XP is the default OS selected, so all you have to do is name it. (Windows XP, for example, is a good name).

5) Choose the amount of RAM to be allocated to this OS (when it's in use). Don't allocate too much because there will be less RAM for your host system to run, which will crash your entire system.

6) Create a new hard disk since you probably don't have one already. Click `Next` to Continue. You will be taken through the Create New Virtual Disk wizard, which will allow you to choose hard disk size, dynamically expanding/fixed size, etc.

7) Review the summary it provides at the end and verify the information is correct. After that, the new Virtual Machine will be created.

8) `Mount` the ISO image by clicking on the `Settings` button. Click the `Storage section` on the left hand side of the window. Click on the `Empty CD medium` in the Storage Tree.

9) Open the Virtual Media Manager, depicted with an icon like a folder with an up arrow, next to CD/DVD Device under `Attributes`.

10) Add the disk image file by clicking `Add`, then choosing the location of the Windows XP ISO image. Select it with `Select`, then press `OK` in the Settings Window. Launch the VirtualBox by pressing `Start`.

11) Install Windows. You should have the Windows installer running now. Remember that since you have not yet install the Guest Additions, you will have to press your Host key (normally Right-Ctrl)

12) Install `Guest Additions`. While the machine is running, under the `Devices` menu, click `Install Guest Additions`, which will launch a setup wizard inside Windows XP. Now you will have OS mouse integration, so you won't have to press the host key to switch between your host and guest. You also can copy and paste between the two operating systems. Now that you have Windows XP installed, you can install programs you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [JSWare](http://www.jsware.net/jsware/vblinux.php5) which states being VBScript engine for Linux systems.